# Holoviews Heatmap X-axis Formatting

Tags: python, heatmap, holoviews

I am currently working on a project that uses holoviews and I request assistance. I am creating a heatmap which plots the value of a model for a given simulation round vs simulation step. The heatmap looks good when there are only a small number of rounds or steps. However, the axises become very crowded if I increase the number of rounds or steps as shown below. Would there be any way to only display a few tick marks on either the X or Y axis (for example only the numbers 0, 15, 30, 45, and 60 on the x-axis in the example shown below)?

[Crowded x-axis due to too many steps in each simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNQhE.png)

My code is as follows:

```
#Generate a heatmap for each element
for element_key in loop_elements:
    heatData = []
    for i in range(runs):
        heatValues = plot_data[element_key][i]['y']
        for j in range(steps):
            heatElement = [(j, i, heatValues[j])]
            heatData += heatElement
    heatImage = hv.HeatMap(heatData, kdims=['x', 'y'], vdims=['z'])
    heatImage.opts(cmap=cmap, colorbar=True, title=element_key, xlabel="Simulation Step", ylabel="Simulation Round", toolbar=None, height=800, width=800)
    heatImage = heatImage.redim.range(z=(0,numStates-1))
    heatImage = heatImage.opts(xticks=5)
    hv.save(heatImage, os.path.join(outputFilepath, "HeatMap" + element_key + ".png"))`
```

Unfortunately using .opts to specify the number of xticks isn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have regularly spaced numerical axes, so you could replace `hv.HeatMap` with `hv.Image`. [hv.Image](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/HeatMap.html) treats the axes as numerical values and can thus skip values, and should allow you to control the xticks. Or you could use xrotation=90 to rotate the labels so they don't overlap. And you can use [hv.QuadMesh](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/QuadMesh.html) if your axes are not regularly spaced.

Comment: Thank you. This was helpful!